# ldapsearch - In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., Data 0, v3838

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

i am trying ldapsearch in the below format

```
dapsearch -x -b "DC=**,DC=****,DC=***" -H ldap://*******:389
```

and that is thowing the following error - In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., Data 0, v3838

I have also tried that with -

```
dapsearch -x -b "DC=**,DC=****,DC=***" -H ldap://*******:389 "cn=admin,DC=**,DC=****,DC=***" - W
```

but still, this is throwing the same error.

Comment: I assume that should be `ldapsearch`, not `dapsearch`. You're not including a filter in your command, so there is really nothing for it to do. That might be the problem.

Comment: Credentials are provided with `-D`, so assuming that `cn=admin,...` is the DN you wish to bind with, it should be prefixed with `-D`.